# Dynamic route not working on NextJS, when linked from inside the app

Tags: heroku, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have now been facing this problem for a couple of days in a NextJS app hosted on Heroku.

First of all this link which points to a dynamic route inside the app is accessible when I paste it directly in the web browser:

https://myexampleapp.herokuapp.com/LYS5569npeck

I tried it successfully on Brave, Firefox and Safari.

But things go wrong when I want to access this same link from inside the app itself.
I have tried using the Link component (import Link from 'next/link';) and a few other ways but it all failed. I get this error:

```
Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).
```

And when I look at the browser console, there is no useful information.

Precisely, this is the kind of information I find:

```
AbortError: Actor 'Conduits' destroyed before query 'RuntimeMessage' was resolved ConduitsParent.sys.mjs:362
    _raceResponses resource://gre/modules/ConduitsParent.sys.mjs:362
```

On the other hand if I replace the link above with another one for testing purpose like: https://www.startpage.com/; it perfectly works.

Is there something basic that I am missing, when using a dynamic route from inside the app itself ?

For further information; this is the page.tsx file for the dynamic route.

```
'use client'

import {FC} from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import AudioRecorderPlayer from '../components/AudioRecorderPlayer'
import AudioList from '../components/AudioList'

interface pageProps {
  params: {channel: string}
}


const NxtJSRoute:FC<pageProps> = ({params}) => {
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      Inside our Next.JS app NxtJSRoute: {params.channel }
      <AudioList chanlID={params.channel} />
      <AudioRecorderPlayer chanlID={params.channel} />
    </main>
  )
}

export default NxtJSRoute
```

Comment: Most probably an error in your particular page, provide your code so it can be debugged

Comment: You may be correct but I don't know how to see that. I just added in the post what I can see in the browser console, which seems pretty useless to me. Because it does not refer to any of my code.

Comment: Cant debug like this, pls post the code of the particular page where you are getting the error

Comment: OK. I just added (at the end of the post) the page.tsx file for the dynamic route having issues. Please have a look.

Comment: ok, remove the params from the page. Try to render it without the props. if it works fine, the error is from the props.

Comment: So, you mean removing all references to params.channel inside the return code ?

Comment: You are right. I just tried it and indeed it works the link from the app gives the same result as the link pasted in the address bar of the browser. So why is there an issue with the props ?

Comment: debug ur params, console it and check it

Comment: OK. I did. The strange thing is that I get the expected parameters in all cases.
It is actually only one parameter. I.E.  params={"channel":"LYS5569npeck"}